# What happened to mongoose.connect method in v4.4.7?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After updating up to mongoose **v4.4.7** mongoose.connect returns only a bunch of some setters and Promise. Before updating it returned other object. Couldn't find any info in documentation.

--- UPDATE ---

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let config = require('./config/env/test');
// config.db === 'mongodb://localhost/testdb'
let db = mongoose.connect(config.db);

console.log(db);
```

The problem is that in v4.4.7 I'm getting *Mongoose* object instead of *MongooseThenable*.

As an example, *gridfs-stream* doesn't work:

```
let gfs = new Grid(db.connection.db, db.mongo);
```

It throws an error:

```
Error stack Error: missing db argument
new Grid(db, mongo)
```